# anchor itemprop url then img

Tags: html, css

A SEO guy wants me to modify my header logo into this, so that our logo will be clickable then redirecting to the base URL:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://domain.com/">Home</a>
  <img itemprop="logo" src="http://domain.com/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

I am having a hard time implementing this since it will affect the design because a link "Home" appears beside the logo, so what I did was something like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://domain.com/"><img itemprop="logo" src="http://domain.com/img/logo.png" /></a>     
</div>
```

Is there a way to implement what he suggested without affecting the current implementation?

Comment: What was wrong with putting the `<img>` inside the `<a>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in the link.

in your html :

```
<a href="/" class="image-link">
    <img src="logo.jpg" />
</a>
```

then in your css, to prevent other link styling :

```
a.image-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Check the result here : http://jsfiddle.net/X4VF2/